# simple assignment not working for me: iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Can someone please explain to me why this simple assignment doesn't work.
Here is the code

    `loanDetails.currency = myCurrency;

        NSLog(@" Value %@",myCurrency);

    NSLog(@" Value %@",loanDetails.currency);

    NSLog(@" Value %@",myCurrency);`

the output is:-

   `2010-05-05 23:00:44.394 ExpenseTracker[3576:207]  Value AFA

   2010-05-05 23:00:44.750 ExpenseTracker[3576:207]  Value (null)

   2010-05-05 23:00:45.095 ExpenseTracker[3576:207]  Value AFA`

And the definition is as:


 `@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *currency;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `loadDetails` nil?

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I was never initializing it. But there was no exception at runtime. In java it would have been a NULL Pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you write `loanDetails.currency = myCurrency`, that's the equivalent of calling `[loanDetails setCurrency:myCurrency]`. So, take a look at your header: did you define it `readonly` by accident? Have you synthesized accessor methods or did you write your own?

Comment: I have added the definition to the question. It was readonly but then the compiler showed an error, so i changed it to the definition described above.